# Second screen to laptop

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, asus-laptop

I have an old laptop (4 year old) on Windows 10.  It works fine but does not detect a second screen.  Windows is up to date and I am sure the second screen/cables etc work as it works with a different laptop. I even uninstalled and reinstalled the graphic device but have no luck.  The second screen is about 3 years old.  The connection should be plug and play but whatever I tried, there was no input to the second screen. I have other laptops which are also a few years old, they do not connect to/detect the second screen either.  I have tried all solutions suggested in Google search.  The cables I used were type c/ type c, usb/type c and hdmi/type c. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

So, does the second screen works with any other PC or laptop? You have said it doesn't. I suppose you have checked that the screen resolution is compatible with the graphics card of the laptops you have tested with. If you have already done cross tests with the video cable and the power cable you are using, and you are (trying to) powering on the display correctly (sometimes displays have an additional power switch in the back, near the power cable connection), maybe the problem is that that display has some type of hardware problem.

Comment: The screen worked on another laptop. You said I should check the screen resolution is compatible with the graphic card, how should I do that? Sorry for the dumb questions I am not a computer person.

Comment: Don't worry. To check the video resolutions allowed by your screen, you simply have to look for its technical specifications sheet on the manufacturer's website or by searching through Google. Once you know which they are, check if your laptop supports any of them. If your laptop supports any of them, configure your laptop to use the supported resolution and you should no longer have the problem.